# Open a form from another form and get a value and then pass it back to the first form

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 forms with text boxes and buttons and I want the first form to open the second form. I then proceed to type a value in the text box in the second form so that when I click the button on the second form it must close and pass the value of the text box to the first form text box.

I have been trying to do this with no luck so far...

I am currently using vb.net in visual studio 2015

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    WithEvents fr2 As New Form2

    Private Sub btngetvalue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btngetvalue.Click
        fr2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub fr2_passvalue() Handles fr2.passvalue
        Me.txtform1.Text = fr2.txtform2.Text
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Form2

    Event passvalue()

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnpassvalue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnpassvalue.Click
        RaiseEvent passvalue()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I have tried accessing the controls directly but it does not work as vb.net now uses classes for everything.  I cannot seem to figure out how to get around this.

Comment: There are gobs of questions relating to this.  Start with some of those under **Related** to rely on *research* rather than *luck*

Comment: Code works.  What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your event to pass a string. Then use the Form2 event to pass the value to the handler.

```
Public Class Form2

    Public Event passvalue(text As String)

    Private Sub btnpassvalue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnpassvalue.Click
        RaiseEvent passvalue(txtform2.Text)
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Handle it in Form1, updating Form1's TextBox.

```
Public Class Form1

    WithEvents fr2 As Form2

    Private Sub btngetvalue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btngetvalue.Click
        fr2 = New Form2()
        fr2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub fr2_passvalue(text As String) Handles fr2.passvalue
        Me.txtform1.Text = text
    End Sub

End Class
```

As you had it before, Form1 was accessing controls on Form2 directly, which defeats the purpose of the event.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply define a global variable (`Public`), which would be accessible from both forms.

Comment: Why `Public`? How about some encapsulation? Here is the problem, this question is answered 100 time already. You need stop answering this, so OP can go and find the answer.